# Pull a subset of data from an array

Tags: php, sql

Is this possible to do?
I have a query that is selecting all records from a table, which the results is based on a time field. This is a schedule of games for 17 weeks. What I am trying to do is create an array of just the current weeks games that have expired. In my code below, every expired game shows in the array. Is it possible to just create this separate array to only include the current week games? I still need to capture all the data, but am trying to create an array of data just for the current week as seen in the row expired portion of the code.

```
$latestweek = getCurrentWeek(); //gives the current week
for($wk=1;$wk<=17;$wk++){   
$games = array();
$sql = "select s.*, (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) > gameTimeEastern or DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) > '" . $cutoffDateTime . "')  as expired ";
$sql .= "from " . DB_PREFIX . "schedule s ";
$sql .= "where s.weekNum = " . $wk . " ";
$sql .= "order by s.gameTimeEastern, s.gameID";

$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
$e = 0;
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $games[$row['gameID']]['gameID'] = $row['gameID'];
    $games[$row['gameID']]['homeID'] = $row['homeID'];
    $games[$row['gameID']]['visitorID'] = $row['visitorID'];
    $games[$row['gameID']]['sWinner'] = $row['result'];
    $games[$row['gameID']]['startTime'] = $row['gameTimeEastern'];      
    if ($row['expired']){
    $survGamesExpired_h[$e]=$row['homeID'];
    $survGamesExpired_v[$e]=$row['visitorID'];
        }

$expiredTeams = array_merge((array)$survGamesExpired_h,(array)$survGamesExpired_v);

}
}
```

Comment: you should alter the querry to only get the data required

Comment: But i need all the data.... I need to create a subset of the data to be used on a restriction in the form this relates to.

Comment: `if($wk == $latestweek){ $thisWeeksGames[] = $row; }`

Comment: I think that works! I swear I tried a variation of that but it wouldn't work. Thanks!